# How to center positive button for AlertDialog (android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog) have only one button

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I used AlertDialog (android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog) for showing levels of game as below

```
AlertDialog dialog;
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.DialogLevelsStyle);
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_game_level, null);
    builder.setView(view)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (dialog != null) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
```

//styles.xml

```
<style name="DialogLevelsStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">#3caaf0</item>
</style>
```

But the dialog display the positive button OK at the button-right of the alert dialog, Please help me!

I update the question by added image: [image]

Comment: try setNeutralButton().

Comment: It display on the bottom - left side of AlertDialog with setNeutralButton()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of [Rules for aligning buttons](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/dialogs.html).

> Action buttons are typically Cancel and/or OK, with OK indicating the preferred or most likely action. However, if the options consist of specific actions such as Close or Wait rather than a confirmation or cancellation of the action described in the content, then all the buttons should be active verbs. Order actions following these rules:
>   The dismissive action of a dialog is always on the left. Dismissive actions return to the user to the previous state.
>   The affirmative actions are on the right. Affirmative actions continue progress toward the user goal that triggered the dialog.

You can't change alignment for your positive/negative buttons. Simply add `Button` to your `view` which you inflate for `dialog` aligned to the center and process it as below:

```
Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
         if (dialog != null) {
             dialog.cancel();
         }
    }
});
```

*Update*
This is how it should look like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
            <TextView
                 android:text="something"
                 android:id="@+id/id1"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

P.S. I cannot check if everything properly, cuz my design window have some problems in Studio, but this is the right way and seems to work fine.

Comment: The problem is my alert dialog have a very long content (have to use ScrollView to scroll to see my content) so if I added a custom button at the end of the view. After that use builder.setView(view) to set the custom view. I have to scroll to end to see the confirm button. I can use the relative layout also to hang the button at the bottom of layout but it displayed strange. And I don't want to approach with this way

Comment: no, you set scrollview on same level with button, so you will see button and scroll in scrollview. I'll update answer in few minutes with example

Comment: Just a side note about your design window, try setting the API level to 21 instead of 22, it solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Marcus, at work I still have 20.0.0 in this project, on another laptop 22.0.0 there is nothing to complain. But thank you, nice though :)

Comment: @Yurets: With the approach, the dialog will display always full size although the content doesn't long enough

Comment: You can play with attributes in `xml` or if you want it to be dynamical you may use this line `getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(height, width);`. This is common solution and there are a lot  ways and a lot of info about it on the Internet in general and on stackoverflow particularly.